# Open Implementation (type hierarchy) functionality in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.7, netbeans6.5

When I have Java code like this:

```
someInterface.someMethod();
```

how do I get Netbeans to show me which classes have implementations of someMethod() (not the interface).

In Eclipse this is done with Ctrl+T, but pressing Ctrl+T on the method did nothing in Netbeans 6.5 and I can't where the type hierarchy functionality is in Netbeans 6.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality already exists in Netbeans:  Alt+F7, check 'Find All Subtypes', and click OK.  Thanks to tkellerer for pointing this out on the Netbeans forums

http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=49638#49638

This is widely overlooked functionality in Netbeans, perhaps because there is no key binding for it, so I've changed my enhancement request to add a key binding for the sequence "Alt+F7, check 'Find All Subtypes', and click OK"?

Comment: I know this is an old post but I have never found that Netbeans 'find implementations' works reliably and I wonder whether it has to do with the context the function is used in. For example do projects in which implement the interface need to be open? I work with a lot of OSGi bundles and very rarely does this function work in Netbeans and it's something that would be extremely useful in that context.

Answer (score 10):

I find that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> works perfectly. :)

Comment: This is the correct equivalent to Eclipse in the newer versions of Netbeans and is better than the "find usages" option.

Comment: Thank you, this is a fantastic shortcut

Answer (score 1):

To get a hierarchy similar to the type hierarchy in Eclipse, right click on the class name, select Navigate, and then Inspect Hierarchy. The keyboard shortcut for this is ALT+SHIFT+F12. By default, it shows you parents of the selected class or interface. However, you can view descendants by using the Filters at the bottom left side. I believe the Show Subtype Hierarchy filter (also toggled by using CTRL+B) is what you want.

This is accurate in NetBeans 6.7.1. I'm going to assume it is similar in 6.5.

Comment: You've misunderstood my question.  I have an interface and want to see which implementations are available for a method of the interface.  Eclipse shows me the various implementations, ALT+SHIFT+F12 doesn't do anything for an interface in Netbeasn 6.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is no comparable functionality in Netbeans.  You can read about it here:

```
http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=49355#49355
```

I've also filed an enhancement request here, which you can vote for:

```
http://www.netbeans.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=172830
```

If you want to see this added to Netbeans please vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, someone has implemented a module to do this, and it works in Netbeans 6.5.1 - perfect for you. I'm hanging out to see an equivalent for 6.7.1. Maybe they should add it to 6.8!

http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaGoToImplementation

Go To Implementation is built in for recent versions of NetBeans. Look in the Navigate context menu.